# How to enable mouse click even on legend with repeat configuration

Tags: vega-lite

i am using repeat configuration and i could able to draw multiple series using this configuration. However when i try to set the params and try to bind with legend, it gives error duplicate signal. I am also using Spec configuration.

Appreciate your help in advance

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/movies.json"},
  "repeat": {"layer": ["US Gross", "Worldwide Gross"]},
  "spec": {
    "mark": "line",
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"bin": true, "field": "IMDB Rating", "type": "quantitative"},
      "y": {
        "aggregate": "mean",
        "field": {"repeat": "layer"},
        "type": "quantitative",
        "title": "Mean of US and Worldwide Gross"
      },
      "color": {"datum": {"repeat": "layer"}, "type": "nominal"}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that this may be a known issue with this particular combination of approaches. I found a similar problem noted on the Vega-Lite GitHub as a bug: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/8168

Comment: Should this be marked as solved...

Answer (score 1):

As noted in my comment above, there appears to be a known bug when combining `"params"` with a `"repeat"` view composition that uses `"layer"` in particular ([GitHub link](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/8168)).

With this in mind, you'll need to refactor your specification to achieve the desired result. Here is a sample based on your provided example ([example link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVICCNsRpwIUmfIC+SnEm1IEENAG1Qs53H01ZyhghMbQBPRRAIOEE4KEw0UEwQnB90HDY-OKUAM3NBZVdUNxAAazgwgF07ECY-ZX1osjh-EBtypWCkWQgstm0Ed1AevPcQAHVevIB3GmU4AAIAcW02CFclAFUAZUXl1ZBKtpBBJBC4bQGQZG1i+r8fJSaoNmU-MniQAA93mvlUYIY4NlcnV0ABJACyABEAEJzABKale4USyX0AEcGJ1MHREaQWkowpoQEgyGRtHxMClLnBOuEclEQSBiEhBADkUkqRisTjsXj2nRovpwTTZHM2Fk5ls5p1lHNxrplNNZjsVq4qk9BL13vThuhSmF2hz9LI2Ag-Cz8SA2A4oHRCaAnv46OxfqAHE5+uhaoFggamSy2agAIxVZmslIABkoACYbHHKkA)). The key approach here is to use a `"fold"` transform to create new "key" and "value" fields from "US Gross" and "Worldwide Gross". With this change, the two lines can now be displayed within a single layer, and the interactive legend will now work.